# (Char)174 returning the value of (Char)0174, why?

Tags: c#, .net, char, ascii

I am working with string delimiters and one of them is « or `174`.  However, when I step through my code it looks like this in the debugger, ®, which is `0174`. See [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/insert-ascii-or-unicode-latin-based-symbols-and-characters-HA010167539.aspx#BM2) for Codes.

This is how I'm doing it in code for reference:

`string fvDelimiter = ((char)174).ToString();`

Comment: Very interesting, I am gonna take a look at this, and if I am showing the same thing.

Comment: See if (char)171 gets you the right one. It's because different fonts have different codes for different chars.

Comment: That worked! However how would I have known this?  So if my IDE font changes then these will be different again?  I guess what I'm asking is how do I ensure it is « all the time regardless of what system compiles/runs it?

Comment: It's not the font, its that Visual Studio uses UTF8 encoding. « is 00AB (0171 decimal) in UTF8 encoding. Look at the UTF code tables not the ASCII ones.

Answer (score 6):

It is all about character encoding. `174` (`AE` in hex) is ® in [Unicode](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/0000-0FFF), which is used internally in `string` by default. But it is `«` in [Extended ASCII code](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/angle-quotes-guillemets-ascii-code-174.html).

Please refer this difference in article you've provided:

> **Inserting ASCII characters**
>
> To insert an ASCII character, press and hold down ALT while typing the character code. For example, to insert the degree (º) symbol, press and hold down ALT while typing 0176 on the numeric keypad.
>
> **Inserting Unicode characters**
>
> To insert a Unicode character, type the character code, press ALT, and then press X. For example, to type a dollar symbol ($), type 0024, press ALT, and then press X.

Comment: Thanks, I knew about the ASCII trick but not the Unicode one.  I noticed that the Unicode shortcut doesn't work in VS2008 for reference.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have seen it is based on the font being used. On Windows I use "Character Map" to check them out. For example the "«" character in the font Calibri is 171.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be it but see my Comment above.

Answer (score 1):

For the simple reason that `char` in c#  represents a `unicode` character  code which match perfectly 0174 and not an `ASCII` code  which is 174

here a code to let you  understand more what I mean

```
            var chrs = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetChars( new byte[]{0174});
            var chrsUtf = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(new byte[] { 0174 });
            var chrsUnicode = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetChars(new byte[] { 0174 }); 
            Debug.WriteLine(chrs[0].ToString());
            Debug.WriteLine(chrsUtf[0].ToString());
            Debug.WriteLine(chrsUnicode[0].ToString());
```